# TCL pattern matching

Tags: regex, tcl

I am new to TCL programming. I want to write a tcl code that check if  any of the patterns HAT GET DOT  present in the given string and if it does, we should display which among the patterns HAT GET DOT is present in the given string.  If more than one pattern is present in the string all the matched patterns should be displayed. I wrote the following code, but it only displays a single pattern even if more than one pattern matches the given string.

---

Can anyone help?

Thank you in advance

Code:

```
set data1 {asdGETdf ferGETfhgDOT} #data1 is the given string
foreach index $test_data1 {
  set result [regexp  {ABC|ACC|ADC|AXC} $index match]
  puts "\n$index"
  if { $result==1} {
    puts "MATCH:$match"
  } else {
    puts "NO MATCH"
  }  
}
```

---

```
output:-asdGETdf
MATCH:GET

ferGETfhgDOT
MATCH:GET
```

---

For the second string I expect it to display `GET` and `DOT` (not `GET` alone as in the output).

I think this is because regexp end the search once a match is found. But how to display all pattern matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply by using the `-all` flag. I would also change your script a bit, by using the `-inline` flag as well to get the results directly instead of relying on `match` variable because when you get more than one match, it will only keep the last match. I also fixed a few errors from your code snippet.

```
set data1 {asdGETdf ferGETfhgDOT} ;#data1 is the given string
foreach index $data1 {
  set result [regexp -all -inline -- {HAT|GET|DOT} $index]
  puts "\n$index"
  if {$result != ""} {
      puts "MATCH: $result"
    } else {
      puts "NO MATCH"
  }  
}
```

[regexp manual](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm)

Comment: Thanks Jerry...As I am new to TCL can you please clarify why we use -- even when we get the answer correct without --

Comment: @joe oh that's just a habit of mine. `--` indicates the end of the flags. It's mostly important if for example your pattern begins with a `-`, it could otherwise cause Tcl to understand it as another flag yet and if that's not a valid flag, give you errors.

Comment: In the above code can i use a variable to store the patterns  HAT GET DOT and use that variable in regexp   like   set pattern {HAT GET DOT} ; regexp -all -inline -- {$pattern} $index

Comment: @joe you can do that, but then you need to drop the braces `{}`. You would do `set pattern {HAT GET DOT}` and then `regexp -all -inline -- $pattern $index`

Comment: @joe Oh, you want the same pattern? Then you need to write it just as you did: `set pattern {HAT|GET|DOT}`